# Spring boot can @RequestBody convert body to Object which has Point/geometry?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-spatial

I have a class Candidate like below which has a member of Type Point which is JTS type. I can pass the name and gender in the body of post request but I do not know how to pass (Point geom) so that @RequestBody can fill the geom member of the Candidate Object.

```
// ..imports here
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;
public class Candidate {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "candidate_sequence",
        sequenceName = "candidate_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1
)
@GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "candidate_sequence"

)
    private  Long id;
    private  String name;
    private Integer gender;    

    @Column(columnDefinition = "geometry(Point,4326)")
    private Point geom;
```

The API interface is like this, how to send the data for member (  private Point geom;) in the http post request

```
   @PostMapping ("/register")
    public Candidate addCandidate(@RequestBody Candidate candidate)
    {
        // candiate.geom is null..
        return candidateService.addCandidate(candidate);
    }
```